# QML Strings in BlackBerry Cascades

Tags: string, qml, blackberry-10

I am trying to build a custom button in newest BlackBerry 10 platform.

**The button should change background image when it is clicked and then change it back when it is clicked the second time**.

*The button logic is fairly simple: once clicked, I check for the type of image currently in the button and change the image source.*

I started with a basic QML custom control which looks like this (stripped of labels and other unimportant things):

```
import bb.cascades 1.0

Container
{

    id: root
    layout: DockLayout
    {
    }

    function clickMe()
    {
        var source = myImage.defaultImageSource.toString();

        console.log(source);

        if (source.endsWith("image.png"))
        {
            myImage.defaultImageSource = "asset:///images/image_pushed.png";
        }
        else
        {
            myImage.defaultImageSource = "asset:///images/image.png";
        }
    }

    ImageButton
    {
        id: myImage
        defaultImageSource: "asset:///images/image.png"
    }

    onCreationCompleted: 
    {
        myImage.clicked.connect(root.clickMe);
    }
}
```

ImageButton click event is connected to JavaScript function **clickMe**. The function fires and the URL is logged to console correctly.

**The problem is the IF clause, because the image_pushed.png is never set. Why is this the problem and how can I implement this button?**

I am looking around for a **only QML solution** for this problem and I found this information:

- the defaultImageSource property is of type QUrl, which does contain
  toString() method.
- toString() method returns QString, which indeed has function endsWith.
- my QML reference: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#endsWith

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within QML QString instances appear to be a normal JavaScript strings. This mapping is done automatically. And Javascript strings don't have a `endsWith` method. You can use the `search` method with an regular expression to achieve the same.

```
if (source.search(/image\.png$/ !== -1) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: If QML QString instances are cast to JS strings, that would explain why endsWith method does not exist. But JS string indeed does have Substring and Substr methods, which do not work either in this case (it was my first attempt at solving this problem).

Comment: The methods you mention start with a lower case letter. You can also certainty in that matter by checking the output of `console.log(typeof(source))`. If it says 'string' it's really an JS string.

Comment: I must say that I went through more testing, and I actually made this working with your concept. Thank you, you are right, the JS string is used, not QString.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create more simple way by using property

for example:

```
Control{
 id : myControl
 property bool state
 ImageButton{
  defaultImageSource : state ? "firstImageAsset.png" : "secondImageAsset.png"
  onClick :{
    myControl.state = !myControl.state
  } 
 }
}
```

Comment: This is how I already implemented the button. But I am still wondering, why the proposed method does not work?

Comment: yup, I think it is like @sebasgo said, javascript string doesn't have endsWith method like Java

Comment: Like I commented on the other answer: I tried the attempt with JavaScript strings, but substring and substr methods do not work either.